# FORM input text to output text as specific link

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink, href

I got a FORM and it works great. But I want to convert users input like this:

textbox: "user writes something here." -> clicks submit and the text is now added to the SQL database in the table, but now with a HREF link attached to it. The output" [user writes something here.](http://google.com)

Let me show you:

```
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Brukernavn:</td>

  <td><input type="text" name="brukernavn" value="" size="24" /></td>

</tr>
```

and when user clicks submit i want the text to be like this:

```
<a href="update.php?oppdaterID=<?php echo $row_persondata2['id']; ?>"> "USERS INPUT"
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/pc.php'); ?>

<?php

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {

function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 

{

  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;



  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);



  switch ($theType) {

    case "text":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";

      break;    

    case "long":

    case "int":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";

      break;

    case "double":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";

      break;

    case "date":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";

      break;

    case "defined":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;

      break;

  }

  return $theValue;

}

}



$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

}



if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO pcbua (time, `navn`, brukernavn, `Type PC`, ServiceTAG, Kommentar, bruker, gruppe) VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['navn'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['brukernavn'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Type_PC'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ServiceTAG'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Kommentar'], "text"),

                                                 GetSQLValueString($_POST['bruker'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['gruppe'], "text"));




  mysql_select_db($database_pc, $pc);

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $pc) or die(mysql_error());

}

?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<body>

<p>Felt med  *  må fylles ut!</p>

<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

  <table align="left">

    <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Navn:</td>

      <td><input type="text" name="navn" value="" size="24" />

    </td>

    </tr>

<tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Brukernavn:</td>

      <td><input type="text" name="brukernavn" value="" size="24" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*PC-Modell:</td>

      <td><select name="Type_PC">

        <option value="" <?php if (!(strcmp("", 1))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>></option>

<option value="Surface Pro 3" <?php if (!(strcmp("Surface Pro 3", 1))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Surface Pro 3</option>

        <option value="Lenovo 530W" <?php if (!(strcmp("Lenovo 530W", 1))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Lenovo 530W</option>

        <option value="Lenovo X220" <?php if (!(strcmp("Lenovo X220", 1))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Lenovo X220</option>

        <option value="MAC" <?php if (!(strcmp("MAC", 1))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>MAC</option>

      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Serienummer:</td>

      <td><input type="text" name="ServiceTAG" value="" size="24" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Gruppe:</td>

      <td><input type="text" name="gruppe" value="" size="24" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Kommentar</td>

      <td><input type="text" name="Kommentar" size="24" /></td>

    </tr>

 <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Bruker</td>

      <td><select name="bruker">

          <option value="<?php global $current_user;

      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo '' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";?>" <?php if (!(strcmp("test", "ikke denne"))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>AutoMode</option>

      </select>

        </td>

    </tr>


    <tr valign="baseline">

      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>

      <td><input type="submit" value="Tilknytt bruker" /></td>

    </tr>

  </table>

  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />

</form>

<p>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And where is this taking place, on the server after a submission, or client-side using JavaScript (if it's client-side then you need to show us the relevant HTML, not the server-side php)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. No javascript here. Posted the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```
if(isset($_POST['brukernavn'])){
echo "<a href='update.php?oppdaterID=".$_POST['brukernavn']."'>your link here</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does it work with HTML form? Added more code in my prev post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        var val = $('#brukernavn').val();
        $('#mydiv').html('<a href="update.php?oppdaterID='+val+'"> USERS INPUT</a>');
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">*Brukernavn:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="brukernavn" id="brukernavn" value="" size="24" /></td>
<td><input type="button" id="mybutton" name="click" value="click" /></td>
</tr>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST method you can show user's input inside the link using **$_POST['brukernavn']** like this:

```
<a href="update.php?oppdaterID=<?php echo $row_persondata2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $_POST['brukernavn']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript function like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildUrl() {
        var str;
        var myInput=document.getElementById("brukernavn");
        str = myInput.value;
       // and here you can build your URL using the variable str
    }
</script>
```

don't forget to add **onclick="buildUrl();"**
 in your submit button. And add an id attribute to your input text so it can be recognized :

```
<td><input type="text" name="brukernavn" id="brukernavn" value="" size="24" /></td>
```